# Excel.Application copy sheet with embedded charts

Tags: php, vba, excel, charts

I have a php page using a Excel.Application to duplicate a sheet containing some data and an embedded chart.

the code is this:

```
$Excel=new COM("Excel.application");
$workbook=$Excel->Workbooks->Open($fileName);

//alternative 1
$workbook->Worksheets("Sheet1")->Copy(NULL,$workbook->Worksheets("Sheet2"));

//alternative 2
$added=$workbook->Worksheets->Add();
$added->Name=$destName;
$workbook->Worksheets($sourceName)->Range("A1:Z100")->Copy($added->Range("A1"));

$workbook->SaveAs($fileNameDest);
```

The result is that the data and the formula are correctly copied and formatted, but the chart in the sheet1 is not copied in the sheet2. No error, no exception, but also no chart for both code alternatives.

Can anyone help me copying this sheet... fully?

Thanks!

Comment: Both of those methods work in pure VBA. I am not a PHP guy but I wanted to chime in at least with that; there is nothing *obviously* wrong and the default functionality of `Copy` method in both cases should also copy the chart (Note: if the chartObject is not within the range A1:Z100, then the second method would not copy the chart).

Comment: The object is in cell B2.

Comment: I suppose is an autentication failure o something like that. I have tested right now this on a Seven Machine with WAMP server and it works. On a windows 2008 server and IIS  fails.

Comment: check the version of Excel that is running on the server. Also make sure you're calling $Excel->Quit because if you don't, every time this runs it will create an Excel process that is never killed.

Comment: As far as workarounds are concerned, have you tried to *also* copy the `ChartObject`? It seems redundant, but I'd be curious if you can copy the chart itself.

Comment: @TMdean: Excel 2010. If I run it on a win7 all works. On win2008 server no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a permission problem:

- Execute "dcomcnfg"
- Open Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
- Search for "Microsoft Excel Application"
- Right-Click on it and open the properties

  - if not exists run "excel.exe -regserver"
- Choose "Identity" tab
- Normally this is set to "the launching user". You have to change this to "the interactive user" or a admin user of your choice.
- Apply these new settings and test your COM application. It should work fine now.

I got it from the comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Comment: Thanks! I have edited a little bit the answare: now it works!

Comment: Good to hear it. That was a bit of a shot in the dark